# Shorthand Insert with Dapper - without specifying columns

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database-connection, dapper

Is there a way to do a shorthand insert with dapper, without specifying all of the columns? I just want to pass in either a single object or a list of objects. All of my model names match my table names in the db.

I am creating a function that copies one entity from another and don't want to specify columns because code management will be minimal if adding another field in the future.

i.e.

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.AppendLine("SELECT *");
sql.AppendLine("FROM Product ");
sql.AppendLine("WHERE Id = @Id");
Product source = connection.Query<Product>(sqlCopy.ToString(), 
    new
    {
        Id = productId
    }, transaction).SingleOrDefault();


// INSERT source entity here without specifying INSERT INTO (COLUMNS)
```

Comment: it is possible but there must not any auto increment field(identity column) and you must be sure about the number of fields.

Comment: @Sanjay do you know how I would do it? And yes the Id column is set to AutoIncrement. I was hoping dapper would handle that for me and not try to insert and Id.

Comment: what you have to do is first exclude identity column form the table in which you want to insert. if you required it then create one table and generate new sequence in that table and get that value in any variable and insert that value in this tablle "sql.AppendLine("insert into table_name values(1,1,1,,,n)");"  let me know if you want more help

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using Dapper.SimplerCRUD (https://github.com/ericdc1/Dapper.SimpleCRUD) or Dapper.Contrib (https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib)?

**Insert Dapper.SimplerCRUD (from github example):**

```
public static int Insert(this IDbConnection connection, object entityToInsert)
```

Example usage:

```
[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
   [Key]
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }

  //Additional properties not in database
  [Editable(false)]
  public string FullName { get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); } }
   public List<User> Friends { get; set; }
   [ReadOnly(true)]
   public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}

var newId = connection.Insert(new User { FirstName = "User", LastName = "Person",  Age = 10 });
```

**Contrib (from github example):**
Insert methods

Insert one entity

```
connection.Insert(new Car { Name = "Volvo" });
```

or a list of entities.

```
connection.Insert(cars);
```